# groovy issue with groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method

Tags: java, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

```
 folder('AAAA'){
        description "BBB"
    }
```

```
pipelineJob("$CCCC"){
   parameters{
                stringParam('branch','master')

            }

}
```

I am new in groovy and trying to handle legacy code, I encounter some code like this

actually I don't know what is it stand for , is this mean a function  and  is folder and pipelineJob a default method?  or just a function name.

I got those error message, but don't know where I can fix it

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: seed.folder() is applicable for argument types: (String, seed$_run_closure1$_closure3) values: [AAA, seed$_run_closure1$_closure3@3f93e4a8]
Possible solutions: collect(), find()
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: seed.folder() is applicable for argument types: (String, seed$_run_closure1$_closure3) values: [AAA, seed$_run_closure1$_closure3@3f93e4a8]
Possible solutions: collect(), find()
        at seed$_run_closure1.doCall(seed.groovy:35)
        at seed.run(seed.groovy:31)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to start here:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/blob/master/docs/Job-DSL-Commands.md#folder

Folder is a method on the Pipeline DSL, but it requires you have Cloudbees plugins installed correctly to use (you might not have the environment setup correctly).

Yes, it's a function call, and the curly brackets after are a Closure (ie think fat arrow functions like in javascript () => println('yeah!') ).  Groovy has powerful functionality around Closures, but it's very dynamic so it's hard to just bump around in IDE with code assist and figure things out.  You'll have to read the docs to figure most things out.

For example description is going to be function too (without the parens), and the next literal is a parameter to it.  But, what object is it invoking that function on?  Well, that's where things get tricky.  It's probably Folder object, but it's either whatever the Closure's this points to or the delegate.  Groovy devs can annotate Closures and such so IDE's can provide assistance, but it doesn't always work out that every dev is prudent to properly annotate things.